# showing timed welcome box before starting application

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have this line working, before I needed to add a feature:

```
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        refreshUI();
    }
```

then I needed to show a welcomeBox for some seconds before showing the MainForm. so I've changed the code like this:

```
    System.Threading.Timer timer;
    GUI.WelcomeBox welcomeBox;
    public MainForm()
    {
        this.Visible = false;
        //Showing welcome box
        welcomeBox = new GUI.WelcomeBox();
        welcomeBox.Visible = true;
        this.Visible = false;

        timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new System.Threading.TimerCallback(delayedActions),null,5000,2000);
    }

    private void delayedActions(object o)
    {
        welcomeBox.Visible = false;
        welcomeBox.Close();
        timer.Dispose();

        InitializeComponent();
        // this line is unreachable, because of error
        refreshUI();
    }
```

but an error occurred at `InitializeComponent()`:  Problem Event Name:  CLR20r3

```
  Problem Signature 01: todoweeklyshedule.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 4fc5385b
  Problem Signature 04: System.Windows.Forms
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4ba1e14e
  Problem Signature 07: a11
  Problem Signature 08: 1b
  Problem Signature 09: System.ArgumentException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: a1ee
  Additional Information 2: a1ee2874cedcaa72f2a8419ddd18697e
  Additional Information 3: a319
  Additional Information 4: a319510eabcccf7de47b58017b885ff3
```

by the way, the MainForm will be shown even with the `this.Visible = false;` line. I have called the MainForm() with `Application.Run(new MainForm());` is this the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't set visible until InitialiseComponents is called, you could probably hack away at this but your real problem is your code is in the wrong place.

Move it all in to program.cs, and call it before Application.Run(new MainForm());
If it were me I'd move the timer on to the welcomebox, get the eventhandler to close it and show it modally as well.

Well actually that's not true, if it were me I wouldn't do this, because I know it would annoy the heck out of any user of the application.

Comment: I agree with tony ,but about the timer thing may be hez just playing around ?

Comment: Playing is a good way to learn, so as long as you learn not to do this. :)

Comment: thanks to all, first I have tried to set the timer in Program.cs but it doesn't work. because... hmm... idk, never mind. now my code is like this: 
            Application.Run(new GUI.WelcomeBox());
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
in Program.cs and set the timer to close the welcomeBox itself. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Move your initialize comonents to before this.visible=false;

```
  public MainForm()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Visible = false;
    //Showing welcome box
    welcomeBox = new GUI.WelcomeBox();
    welcomeBox.Visible = true;
    this.Visible = false;

    timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new System.Threading.TimerCallback(delayedActions),null,5000,2000);
```

Next best recommendation would be to make your welcome box your main form, then have it change into what your main form is, that would be a bit of rewriting, but worth it.

Last suggestion would be to load your main form and call the welcome box as a showdialog(), which closes after your timer tells it to.